# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1221, 50, 50, 1)

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im trying to run a model with `xtrain=(1221,50,50,1)`
at the time of `model.fit` its showing this error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1221, 50, 50, 1)

im using these functions:

```py
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=Adadelta(lr=0.8), metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x=ZZ, y=yyy, batch_size=128, epochs=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

when i increase the dimensions to (1221,50,50,1,1)
using expand_dims im getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (16, 50, 50, 1) but got array with shape (1221,50, 50, 1, 1)

Idk where im getting wrong

this is my model

````
input_layer = Input((16, 50, 50, 1))
## convolutional layers
conv_layer1 = Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
conv_layer2 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(conv_layer1)

## add max pooling to obtain the most imformatic features
pooling_layer1 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv_layer2)

conv_layer3 = Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(pooling_layer1)
conv_layer4 = Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(conv_layer3)
pooling_layer2 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv_layer4)

## perform batch normalization on the convolution outputs before feeding it to MLP architecture
pooling_layer2 = BatchNormalization()(pooling_layer2)
flatten_layer = Flatten()(pooling_layer2)

## create an MLP architecture with dense layers : 4096 -> 512 -> 10
## add dropouts to avoid overfitting / perform regularization
dense_layer1 = Dense(units=2048, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dense_layer1 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer2)
output_layer = Dense(units=6, activation='softmax')(dense_layer2) #Use 5 instead of 1

## define the model with input layer and output layer
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)```
````

Comment: please share the code where you defined your model layers.

Comment: Can you provide the model definition, the error probably lays there

Comment: Please show the whole model.

Comment: I have shown the model @RishabhSahrawat

Comment: model @faucozo  ,MH394

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_layer = Input((16, 50, 50, 1))
```

This line specify that an input has a shape of `(16, 50, 50 ,1)`. You're passing to the network the whole `(1221, 50, 50, 1)`vector. You need to reshape to `(X, 16, 50, 50, 1)` so that an element of the vector has the shape desired `(16, 50, 50, 1)`.

Comment: so i need to reshape it in form of (1221,16,50,50,1)

Comment: what is the x in the reshape  my input or something else

Comment: I don't know your problem, but I guess you want to feed a shape `(16, 50, 50, 1)`to your Conv3D. To do so you need to give batches of `(16, 50, 50, 1)`array to your model. Shapes in keras for Conv3D are `(batch, spatial_dim1, spatial_dim2, spatial_dim3, channels)`. In your case spatial_dim1=16, spatial_dim2=50, spatial_dim3=50, channels=1. Since you specified in the `fit` operation that you work with 128 per batch, you just need to give your whole data to the `fit`. Which means that you reshape your input data to `(X, 16, 50, 50, 1)`where X is 1221/16 if you have 1221 samples of `(50, 50, 1)`

Comment: You could give the code of your data array creation so that I can help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `xtrain`, it consists 1221 images of shape (50,50,1) however, the Conv3D is expecting images of shape `(16,50,50,1)`.

In case you are confused, the `input_layer` to Conv2D doesn't require the total number of images value. It only requires the shape of the image coming to it.

For your help, you can look at [this](https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/3d-convolutions-understanding-use-case) example how the images are being passed and set.

Comment: thank you for the example i will get back to u after watch the example

Answer (score 0):

I get what mistake I did my x_train should have consist of (X,16,50,50,1)
but the 16 was not there.
this is due to an error in which the input was taken.

Thank you for your help
Rishabh Sahrawat 
Orphee Faucoz
MH304